# iOS 9.3 Today View Height limited

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9, today-extension, ios9.3

I have an application that provides a Today extension that uses a Table View Controller as it's VC. Before iOS 9.3, I would simply call

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: theContentWidth, height: theContentHeight)
```

to change the height of the extension VC. However after updating to iOS 9.3 and Xcode 7.3, the height of the VC is being limited to 230px, whereas before I was able to resize it up to about 540px.

I've tried replacing the Table View Controller with a plain View Controller and adding in a UITableView with AutoLayout constraints with the hopes of restoring the correct resizing functionality by adjusting the constant of the height constraint of the tableview, but with no luck.

Anyone experiencing this same issue or have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, turns out Xcode was causing the issue. After exporting the .ipa and installing via iTunes it worked just fine. Must be a bug in Xcode 7.3